# How to get text from binary file?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, binaryfiles

I have a binary file, if i open it with some text editor i see something like this

```
...á�� ©Ú�ø¬�ø¬hŸˇø$)�� ©Ú(‡���� ©Ú(‡��ø¬àŸˇø‰...
```

it's not human readable form but it doesn't matter because i need it in this form.
But when i try to load this file is objective c i get something like this

```
...6e007400 65006e00 74007300 2f004400 65007600 65006c00 6f007000...
```

it looks nice but it's not what i need.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
```

This is the way I load content of this file.

I tried also init string with this NSData object with few encodings. NSASCIIStringEncoding was closest, it gave me first 4 letters of this file, but the rest was something like `\u00a8\u0000\u0000\u0000Hh\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000`

Comment: The string `\u00a8\u00...` was when you logged the contents? Or when presented in a text view (or similar)? And why do you want the non-text to be displayed as text?

Comment: No, this string was on log of server where i send it, on it was only first 4 letters of this text file. And i need text because i need to send this text on the server.

Comment: `\u00a8\u0000\u0000\u0000Hh\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000` is text, just in a different form to `á�� ©Ú�ø¬�ø¬hŸˇø$)��`. So long as you are consistent there isn't a lot of difference. Why not just send the file or use base64?

Comment: When i use NSDataBase64Encoding... it returns null. I need to send text content of this file, not file.

Comment: With `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:` ?

Comment: Since it's a binary file, is it supposed to be "human readable"?

Comment: If you just want to look at the strings in the file in the Terminal, you can use `strings yourFile`

Comment: I tried but i get normal letters not strange symbols like in original file.

Comment: Well, according to `man strings` in `Terminal.app`, it uses ASCII. So its the encoding you're looking for. Maybe a closer look to the `strings` command will help you.